# Showing that $\mathbb{P}\left[2\log a \leq nZ_n + n\leq 2\log b\right] \to 0$ using Chebyshev's Inequality?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose I have that:

$$
\mathbb{P}\left[2\log a \leq nZ_n + n\leq 2\log b\right]
$$

where $Z_n$ is a $Gamma(n,1)$ random variable and $0 \leq a < b$. I am trying to show that as $n \to \infty$, $\mathbb{P}\left[2\log a \leq nZ_n + n\leq 2\log b\right] = 0$.

This was mentioned in a previous post and the suggested line of attack was Chebyshev's Inequality. However, here I have asymmetry on the sides. Is there a way to use Chebyshev's Inequality here?

Comment: Are there any assumptions on $a$ and $b$?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo Hi, yes, forgot to mention, $0 \leq a <b$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have, for sufficiently large $n$
\begin{align}
\Pr(2\log a \leq nZ_n + n \leq 2 \log b) &\leq \Pr(nZ_n + n \leq 2 \log b) \\
& \leq \Pr(nZ_n +n\leq n^2 + n - (n^2 + n - 2\log b)) \\
& \leq \frac{n^3}{n^3 + (n^2 + n - 2\log b)^2}
\end{align}
which approaches $0$ when $n \rightarrow \infty$. Above we use the [one-sided Chebyshev's inequality](http://www.ams.sunysb.edu/~jsbm/courses/311/cheby.pdf) and the fact 
$$
\mathsf{E}(nZ_n + n) = n^2 + n\quad \text{and}\quad \mathsf{Var}(nZ_n + n) = n^3
$$